# Appositive or incorrect grammar?

Tags: grammar

P. 17 of "The C Programming Language" 2nd Edition by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie:

> It's possible to get carried away and create impenetrable code, however, a tendency that we will try to curb.

Is the clause after the second comma just a long appositive?

Comment: It is missing something. however, **that is** a tendency.

Comment: It looks right as is. The tendency is not impenetrable code, but the whole "to get carried away and ... code."

Comment: The sentence is fine, but the expression "a tendency that we will try to curb" is not an appositive since it is ascriptive not specifying.

Answer (score 1):

Write it like this to make it clear :

> It's possible to get carried away and create impenetrable code, however, a tendency that we will try to curb.
> However, it's possible to get carried away and create impenetrable code, a tendency that we will try to curb.
> However, it's possible to get X, a tendency that we will try to curb.
> However, it's possible to get X. It is a tendency to get X. We will try to curb that tendency.

The original is Concise & Correct !

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect grammar. There is no context indicating that "however" governs the first clause. Therefore, the reader interprets the first clause as the main clause and expects "however," to introduce a subsidiary clause. However, we get not a second clause but a noun phrase.

A possible rephrase using the same words:

It's possible to get carried away and create impenetrable code, a tendency that we will, however, try to curb.

A possible rephrase using two sentences rather than using an appositive:

It's possible to get carried away and create impenetrable code. However, we will try to curb this tendency.

Comment: It's not ungrammatical, but I agree that there's a garden-pathiness about it. I'd just adjust one of the signposts slightly: << It's possible to get carried away and create impenetrable code, however – a tendency that we will try to curb. >>